# JPA @JoinTable with composite (2 column) primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

In a spring-boot app, I've got the following entity definition:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "username", length = 100)
    private String username;

    @JoinTable(name = "userrole", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "username") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role") }
    )
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Role> roles;`
```

I'm using Spring-data-jpa,Hibernate with H2 as the database.
The trouble is that spring-data-jpa, hibernate always generate/creates the join table (DDL) 'userrole' with a single column primary key. e.g. 'username'.
Hence, if records such as {'username', 'user_role'} and {'username', 'admin_role'} is inserted in the join table ('userrole'), the next insert fails with an error due to the 'duplicate' primary key.

I've tried using both columns in the above definition, as well as the following variation:

```
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumns({
           @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
           @JoinColumn(name = "role") })
    private List<Role> roles;`
```

But that they resulted in the same or worse problems, e.g. and in the latter, even table creation fails because only a single column is used as primary key for the jointable. Role is simply another table with 2 columns 'role' and 'description', basically a role catalog.

How do we specify to JPA that the @JoinTable should use both 'username' and 'role' columns as composite primary keys?

edit:
I tried using an independent table/entity as suggested, thanks @Kamil Bęben

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "username", length = 100)
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        mappedBy = "username",
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @ElementCollection
    private List<UserRole> roles;
```

UserRole is defined as such

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "userrole")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userrole_seq")
    Long id;    
    
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "username", length = 100)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "role", length = 50)
    private String role;
```

the repository for that user-roles join table is defined as

```
@Repository
public interface UserRoleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRole, Long> {

    UserRole findByUsernameAndRole(String username, String role);
    
    List<UserRole> findByUsername(String username); 
        
    List<UserRole> findByRole(String role); 
    
}
```

Admittedly, ugly, but that it works. And that somehow, it seemed to use the correct findByUsername() method to retrieve the roles as is relevant to the user, probably related to the 'mappedBy' clause. 'black magic'! There's lots more that I'd still need to find my way around JPA, Spring, Spring-data

edit2:
further update:
the original @JoinTable works as well.
But that the relations need to be specified as @ManyToMany

```
    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "usersroles", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "username") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role") }
    )
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

This creates 2 column primary keys as expected for the 'users-roles' table

Thanks to @Roman

Comment: Why is `roles` annotated with `@OneToMany`? Shouldn't that be `@ManyToMany`?

Comment: yup it is actually \@ManyToMany, but that from the parent class User, it'd look more like \@OneToMany as the user would have multiple roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Role only has two columns, eg user_id and role, the way to map this in jpa would be as following

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "role")
List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Otherwise, jpa really requires each entity's identifier and join columns to be separate columns, so Role entity would have to have columns like id, user_id and role_name. Could look like this .:

```
class Role {
  @Id
  Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id");
  User user;
  String roleName;
  // Other fields
}
```

And in the User entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user") // user is Field's name, not a column
List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

[Further reading](https://thorben-janssen.com/collections-hibernate-jpa/)

Comment: Thanks ! 
I've tried the \@ElementCollection method and it works

I think explicitly defining the user-roles join table as an entity is probably a better practice ! I'd work the other, which is to have the user-roles join table defined as a standalone entity